# Asql select join and delete together

Tags: mysql, sql

table master

```
|  id  |   user  |
|  1   |  user1  |
|  3   |  user2  |
|  4   |  user3  |
```

table ver

```
| id_v |  value  |
|  2   |  value1 |
|  3   |  value2 |
```

I must delete id_v 2 on table ver

I' have this query

```
DELETE FROM `ver` WHERE id_v in (SELECT v.id_v
FROM master m
RIGHT JOIN ver v
ON m.id = v.id_v
WHERE m.id IS NULL)
```

but this is the error

> You can't specify target table 'ver' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using the following

```
delete 
v
from ver v
left join master m on m.id = v.id_v
where m.id is null
```

**[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40155/2)**

Comment: is the inverse i must delete ver elements not present in master

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE FROM `ver` WHERE id_v in ( SELECT id_v from
(SELECT v.id_v FROM master m
RIGHT JOIN ver v
ON m.id = v.id_v
WHERE m.id IS NULL) as temp )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a subquery of table ver to delete something from table ver itself.

You mean this?

```
delete from ver where id_v is null;
```